# How to update a model's "updated_at" field only for a subset of column updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, data-modeling

There is a typical blog application. Each user has_many posts. Each post has_many tags. 
I'm sorting each post by updated_at so the most recently updated post will show up on top. So for example, if I update a post's content, the post will come up to the top. However, this also happens when I just add a tag, since a tag is connected to its corresponding post.

I only want the content update to change updated_at field. I don't want updated_at for a post to be changed because I added a tag. Is there a way to do this? Or any other way to achieve something like this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you monkey-patch "updated_at=" and only honor it (set the backing source) if a certain flag is passed? (I don't use RoR so have no idea when/how the field is updated.)

Comment: You could try to set _touch_ to _false_ in your tags model like `belongs_to :post, :touch => false`. Maybe this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches spring to mind:

1. Don't use `:updated_at` for the purpose you are using it for.  Instead create a new column, say `:post_updated_at`, and update it manually on each save that you want to cause the post to move to the top.  Rails provides a convenient model mehod for this:

   ```
   mypost.touch :post_updated_at
   ```
2. When you are updating a column and want `:updated_at` to remain untouched, use the [`#update_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) method, which directly updates the column in the database with the value you give it.  Note that it writes the value to the database verbatim, so you will have to be clever if the column in question is a fancy `serialize` column or similar.

Comment: Yes come to think of it, that makes sense :)

Comment: @michael what is the reason behind suggesting not to use the :updated_at for the purpose..?

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura: Aside from serving as criteria for presenting newly changed data to the user, it is also useful to reserve `:updated_at` for any direct or related change to the row for things like incremental search indexing and troubleshooting. I'm generally more eager to increase the frequency of updating `:updated_at` (e.g. changes in `has_many` associations) than reducing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a replacement for `save` which lets you blacklist "boring" attributes, ie those which don't trigger a timestamp update. It relies on the Rails 4+ `update_columns` method to suppress callback methods during a save (be careful about suppressing those).

```
# Here we configure attribs that won't trigger the timestamp update
IGNORED_ATTRIBS = Set.new %w(reviewed_at view_count)

# A "save" replacement
def fussy_save

  # Calculate any ignored attributes that are pending a save
  all_changed_attribs = Set.new(self.changed_attributes.keys)
  ignored_changed_attribs = IGNORED_ATTRIBS.intersection all_changed_attribs

  # Save the ignored attributes without triggering updated_at
  if ignored_changed_attribs.present?
    self.update_columns self.attributes.slice(*ignored_changed_attribs)
  end

 # perform a normal save only if there are additional attributes present
  if !all_changed_attribs.subset?(IGNORED_ATTRIBS)
    save
  end

end
```

Implementation note:

The final line above is a regular save. I initially tried doing a save without the check, on the basis that nothing should happen if the ignored attributes have already been saved (since `save` does nothing, and doesn't update timestamp, if no attribs are saved). But I discovered that `changed_attributes` is actually Rails' internal, definitive, reference, not just a convenience for developers (not too surprising :). It feels dangerous to start messing with that, so instead I just perform a check and all changed attributes will be saved in the SQL (including the ones just saved by update_columns), but only if there are non-ignored attributes present.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781682/how-to-update-a-timestamp-only-when-certain-attributes-are-updated for a much shorter solution.