# How to update a timestamp only when certain attributes are updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a timestamp column that only updates when certain fields are updated, for example, if the name of a product changes, the attributes_updated_at field should be updated with Time.now.  I do not want the field to be updated in the case that a foreign key association is added, or if `product.status` changes from `'pending'` to `'active'`.

Is there a way to define this simply in a model?

Comment: you can simple use in `before_save` so for update and save  `Model.record_timestamps = false if product.status.changed? || self.association_id.changed?`

Comment: @RajarshiDas, that seems like a great suggestion.  Can you guide me on how I might use that?  Is it a class level definition?

Comment: let user model you have to write `before_save :stop_update_time_stamps` and then write the method `def stop_update_time_stamp User.record_timestamps = false if product.status.changed? || self.association_id.changed? end` like this

Comment: I can create a post if it will fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try it

Let consider you have `Product` model

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   before_save :stop_update_time_stamps

   def stop_update_time_stamp
     self.class.record_timestamps = false if self.status.changed? || self.user_id.changed? 
   end  
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is a database problem and not a ruby problem.

You can achieve the desired behavior using for example a database trigger(this is mysql code).

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_product AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.name <> OLD.name) or (NEW.category <> OLD.category)
   THEN set NEW.updated_at = NOW();

END;
```

Comment: This seems like a roundabout solution that does not address the problem within the framework.  I do believe it would work, but I'm working under the assumption that I do not have access to create triggers for a DB.  Thank you though.